# Having issues with styling my page with CSS

Tags: css

My website has a problem with the archive page. I'm not understanding what it's doing as the .entry-content style is perfectly set up for what it should look like as it does on the blog page. However when you head over to the [archive page](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress/?m=201203) it's condensed and tight and the footer even has a gap to the left of it. My categories do the same thing, however all the rest of the styles on the site are fine. I'm using firebug to see the styles but through that but I can't even see what might be happening as the .entry-content CSS style doesn't show up.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would change the CSS for the footer from `position: relative` to `position: absolute` and add `margin-left: 0px;` and see if the problem goes away

Comment: It worked of course however I need it to be relatively positioned for the dynamic content in each page.

Comment: I would assume the margin-left: 0px would work even with relative positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `height` property from

```
.entry-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px; /* remove this */
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a class named "date" applied to body tag in archive page so just remove padding-left from that class & your website footer will be fixed.

```
.date {
 color: #666;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 10px;/* Remove This*/
 min-height: 10px;
}
```

Now, the Posted on date issue: I can see that you have used wrapped post header inside  tag but its wrapped inside  tag in archive page & header display is set to block. So just change the header tag to span in archive page. Below is your code change header to span. Its good main consistency in all your pages code.

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="title">
      <a href="http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress/?p=10" title="Permalink to Looking for someone to hire?" rel="bookmark">Looking for someone to hire?</a>
   </h1>
   <div class="entry-meta">Posted on: March 27, 2012 </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning wordpress and this is my first wordpress website. I used toolbox, a theme I found. So I'll be opening up wordpress and learning more about it for future projects I do with it.

Comment: Hey! Even i have completed my first wordpress blog few days before.

Here are some nice tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/